# Am I properly simplifying this geometric progression?

Tags: recurrence-relations

I'm studying recurrence relations and am given:

$T(n) = 2 \cdot T(n-1) - 1$

with an initial condition that $T(1) = 3$.

I worked through the first few recurrences:

$T(n-1) = 2^2 \cdot T(n-2) - 2 - 1$

$T(n-2) = 2^3 \cdot T(n-3) - 2^2 - 2 - 1$

and so forth, and came the conclusion that the pattern

$2^k \cdot T(n-k) - 2^{k-1} - 2^{k-2} - ... 2 - 1$

represents this relation. Since we have T(1) = 3, there must be some $n$ and $k$ such that $n-k = 1$, so $k= n - 1$. Substituting:

$2^{n-1} \cdot T(1) - 2^{n-2} - 2^{n-3} - ... 2 - 1$

but T(1) = 3, so...

$2^{n-1} \cdot 3 - 2^{n-2} - 2^{n-3} - ... 2 - 1$

Factoring out a $-1$ I have something that looks for all the world like a geometric progression:

$2^{n-1} \cdot 3 - (1 + 2 + ... + 2^{n-3} + 2^{n-2})$

However, I'm convinced my progression is missing a term, namely $2^{n-1}$. It's outside the progression, being multiplied by three. In my notes, my instructor simplified the progression to:

$\frac{2^{n-1} - 1}{2 - 1}$

I'm confused about where $n-1$ in the exponent of the geometric progression simplification is coming from. I eventually solve the recurrence relation as :

$3 \cdot 2^{n-1} - 2^{n-1} + 1 = 2^n + 1$

Is my understanding of the simplification of the geometric progression correct?

Comment: It's very unfortunate that good questions like yours get downvotes (though so far only 1), whereas some lousy questions that consist of nothing more than the homework problem get plenty of upvotes. But don't worry, you have asked an excellent question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The left sides of your second and third equations should be $T(n)$, not what you have written.  Under "Factoring out a $-1$" it would be better to end with $2^{n-3}+2^{n-2}$ to maintain the pattern of the exponents increasing by $1$.  Your progression does end with $2^{n-2}$.  That is why the numerator of the sum has $2^{n-1}$.  If you look at the formula for the sum of a finite geometric progression, the exponent is $1$ more than the highest term:
$$1+r+r^2+\ldots +r^k=\frac {r^{k+1}-1}{r-1}$$
When you add $1$ to $n-2$ you get $n-1$ so your teacher's sum of the progression is correct.  Your final answer is also correct.

Comment: Also, why is $T(n-1)$ and $T(n-2)$ inappropriate? This is the way my instructor formed the process of expanding the recurrence relation. I would love to understand this point better so that I may be clearer when communicating with others.

Comment: You started with $T(n-1)$ on the right, then substituted $2T(n-2)-1$ for it.  You shouldn't change the left hand side when you do this.  I had a typo in the formula for summing a geometric series, now fixed.

Answer (score 5):

You've gotten an answer to your specific question, but I want to explain how to **correctly** solve the question in a **mathematically rigorous** manner, and not appealing to handwaving. (Every occurrence of "···" is an instance of lack of rigour.)

---

**Working 1**

$T(n) - 2·T(n-1) = -1$.

$2 · ( T(n-1) - 2·T(n-2) ) = 2·-1$.   // We do this to match and cancel the $2·T(n-1)$.

$4 · ( T(n-2) - 2·T(n-3) ) = 4·-1$.   // We do this to match and cancel the $4·T(n-2)$.

...   // Not rigorous! We need to express the pattern rigorously.

**Solution 1**

Take any integer $n > 1$.

$T(n) - 2·T(n-1) = -1$.

$2^k · ( T(n-k) - 2·T(n-k-1) ) = -2^k$ for every integer $k < n-1$.

$\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} ( 2^k · ( T(n-k) - 2·T(n-k-1) ) ) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} -2^k$.

$\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} ( 2^k·T(n-k) - 2^{k+1}·T(n-k-1) ) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} -2^k$.

$\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} (2^k·T(n-k)) - \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} (2^{k+1}·T(n-k-1)) = -2^{n-1} + 1$.

$\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} (2^k·T(n-k)) - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (2^k·T(n-k)) = -2^{n-1} + 1$.

$2^0·T(n-0) - 2^{n-1}·T(n-(n-1)) = -2^{n-1} + 1$.

$T(n) = 2^{n-1}·T(1) - 2^{n-1} + 1 = 2^n + 1$.

Check that $T(1) = 2^1 + 1$ as well, because the above proof assumed $n > 1$.

---

**Solution 2**

Take any integer $n > 1$.

$T(n) - 2·T(n-1) = -1$.

$( T(n) - 2·T(n-1) ) / 2^n = -1/2^n$.

$T(n)/2^n - T(n-1)/2^{n-1} = -1/2^n$.

Take any integer $m > 1$.

$\sum_{n=2}^m ( T(n)/2^n - T(n-1)/2^{n-1} ) = \sum_{n=2}^m -1/2^n$.

$\sum_{n=2}^m (T(n)/2^n) - \sum_{n=2}^m (T(n-1)/2^{n-1}) = -1/2 + 1/2^m$.

$\sum_{n=2}^m (T(n)/2^n) - \sum_{n=1}^{m-1} (T(n)/2^n) = -1/2 + 1/2^m$.

$T(m)/2^m - T(1)/2^1 = -1/2 + 1/2^m$.

$T(m) = 2^m·(T(1)/2-1/2) + 1 = 2^m + 1$.

Check that $T(1) = 2^1+1$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure that your calculation is right you should try to verify your calculations.

The first ten numbers of the first recurrence relation

$$T(n) = 2*T(n-1) - 1$$

are

$$3,5,9,17,33,65,129,257,513,1025$$

ten numbers of the second recurrence relation

$$T(n-1) = 2^2*T(n-2) - 2 - 1$$

are

$$3,9,33,129,513,2049,8193,32769,131073,524289$$

So these are different calculations, so something went wrong.

---

The sentence "the pattern ... represents this relation" is rather unclear. Give it a precise meaning and try to verify it.